# Flask SocketIO - connect client to server immediately after server start

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I've created a single socket endpoint on the server side that looks like this:

#### Server.py

```
from client import sockio_client
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('status_update')
def status_update(data):
    print('got something: ',data)

@app.before_first_request
def start_ws_client():
    # now that server is started, connect client
    sockio_client.connect('http://localhost:5000')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)
```

And the corresponding client:

#### Client.py

```
import socketio
from threading import Thread

sockio_client = socketio.Client()
# wait to connect until server actually started
# bunch of code

def updater():
    while True:
        sockio_client.emit('status_update', 42)
        time.sleep(10)

t = Thread(target=updater)
t.start()
```

I've got a single background thread running outside of the server and I would like to update clients with the data it periodically emits. I'm sure there is more than one way to do this, but the two options I came up with were to either (i) pass a reference to the `socketio` object in `server.py` above to the update function in client by encapsulating the update function in an object or closure which has a reference to the `socketio` object, or (ii) just use a websocket client from the background job to communicate to the server.  Option one just felt funny so I went with (ii), which feels... okish

Now obviously the server has to be running before I can connect the client, so I thought I could use the `before_first_request` decorator to make sure I only attempt to connect the client after the server has started.  However every time I try, I get:

> `socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection refused by the server`

At this point the server is definitely running, but no connections will be accepted.  If I were to comment out the `sockio_client.connect` in `server.py`, and connect from an entirely separate script, everything works as expected.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, if there are much better ways to do this, please tear it apart.

Comment: I can't reproduce even after adding the missing imports and fixing the syntax error. Would you provide the environment in which you're running this?

Comment: Thanks for having a look @MichaelRuth - I originally typed this up as a quick example, not meant to actually be runnable - so there were a few problems with imports and syntax as you pointed out.  I've fixed those - but the basic problem remains - I cannot seem to connect to a running SocketIO server from within the same application in which the server was started.  Firing up an entirely separate program works just fine.

Comment: Oh - and windows 7 (corporate environment, can't control that)

Comment: bummer, I don't have access to a Windows environment. Off the top of my head I'd say take a look at your firewall settings, but I'm at the end of what I can do. Hopefully someone with a Windows env can look at this.

Comment: I just went with the "pass a reference to `socketio`" approach to get it done - maybe not the cleanest but it works.  I highly doubt it's firewall since I can reach the server from a separate file, once the server is running locally.  I think I've narrowed it down to the `before_first_request` - it's as if the client is trying to connect to a server that has not yet started at this point.  The documentation seems to indicate that this is exactly the use-case for this decorator though - to run code which executes after server start but before first request, so i'm not sure why it can't connect.